# Using socat to copy multicast from one network to another

Tags: multicast, socat

I'm trying to copy/rebroadcast an incoming multicast channel from one address to another, so I figured socat would let me do this.

If I already have something joined to that network and logging to console:

```
./socat UDP4-RECVFROM:14314,reuseaddr - | ./socat - udp-sendto:239.160.2.13:14314
```

or if I don't:

```
./socat UDP4-RECVFROM:14314,ip-add-membership=233.158.8.5:0.0.0.0 - | ./socat - udp-sendto:239.160.2.13:14314
```

But these exit after the first packet or so, so then I figured adding, `fork`  would help but that just seems to create another publisher for every packet received so there was a massive echo.

Any suggestions please on how to fix this? I've tried the [dest-unreach](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html) cheatsheet but nothing there seems to match my exact need. I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Comment: Not sure I understand this, nor can I test, but I think you only need one instance of `socat` rather than 2 joined by a pipe. More like `socat recvfrom:... sendto:...`

Comment: seems my echo was because i was re-publishing on the same  port as receiving. It seems each forked socat forwards one message then dies, and it seems ok. the command I finally went for was ```./socat UDP4-RECVFROM:14314,reuseaddr,fork udp-sendto:239.160.2.13:14315```